# Composer not working on command prompt Windows 7

Tags: windows, command-line, composer-php

I installed Composer via Composer windows installer and it installed to the path `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup`. The `composer.phar` file is in the `bin` folder in the directory (`C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin`). I have added the Composer PATH to the environment variable. But even after that, I can't make Composer get start by typing `composer` in the command prompt. Can you help me? I have tried installing it manually in different directories and so far no success.

I have downloaded Console2 and inside it, Composer works just fine. But the windows command prompt doesn't do anything unless I'm in the installation directory.

Comment: This sounds quite weird because Console2 is not a real console itself but a wrapper for other consoles (such as Windows command line). So can you tell us which console did you use inside Console2? Does Composers `bin` directory show up if you run `echo %PATH%` in your Windows command line?

Comment: Yes it shows. I don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: Sorry for asking that but are you really sure there is no typo in your `PATH`. Can you add your full `PATH` to your question above please? Is there also a `composer.bat` in your `bin` directory?

Comment: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
In this directory, there are 3 files. (composer, composer.bat, composer.phar). 
composer.bat have these lines. 
@echo off

php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*